# XAMPP is not working in window

Tags: apache, xampp

Trying to install XAMPP v3.2.1 on windows8 and it gives me the following error:

```
23:30:36  [Apache]  Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
23:30:36  [Apache]  This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
23:30:36  [Apache]  improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
23:30:36  [Apache]  Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
23:30:36  [Apache]  the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
23:30:36  [Apache]  If you need more help, copy and post this
23:30:36  [Apache]  entire log window on the forums
```

I actually tried so many things but I don't know what to do now. Any suggestions?

Comment: What does your windows event log say? What about error logs (or rest of)? Also, if you ever want to do more than play around with this, you should consider switching to linux server side (as well as not using apache, php, or mysql, but that's a different story ...)

Comment: actually log file is empty and i have to work on windows 8 so u have any idea...?? then pls tell me Thanks in Advance

Comment: And what is in your events viewer? If it's a firewall issue (->blocked port) you might find a clue there. Also you might want to try asking your question again on apache provided help systems (lists, usenet groups, ...), for that see here: http://httpd.apache.org/lists.html#http-users

Comment: ohk Thanks griffin Thanks for your Help i'll post my another comment after seeing them :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually Skype is causing this issue so there are two ways to resolve this issue.

1. Quit the Skype so it'll release port 80 and 433.
2. Go to Skype Tools-> options -> Advanced -> Connection and unchecked port 80 after this you need to restart your Skype and try to run the XAMPP now it'll not throw any issue as port 80 and 443 is free to use

---

In Some cases IIS Server is using port 80 or 443. which cause XAMPP to stop running. To stop IIS Server you can follow this step.

- Go to start Menu type Internet Information Services select this and stop it's service which will release port 80 and 443.

Answer (score 4):

Try to comment out all SSL related stuffs in "apache-ssl.conf". The simplest way to access and edit this file is : from the Control Panel of XAMPP - > (Apache) Config.

Comment: so this will release port 80 and 443 as this issue is caused by blocking port(80 and 443)

Answer (score 0):

Here are some options to solve the problem :

Option 1 : Stop other services directly from XAMPP control panel

On XAMPP control panel click Services button (see image above), a new window with services list will appear (see image below, filename is services.msc, extra info).

[image]
Then scrolled down to look for

1. World Wide Web Publishing Service. If it is running, stop it (stop this service option on the left after clicking on the service name) or double clicked on it and clicked STOP (if this service status is Started).
2. Internet Information Services  (IIS). If it is running, stop it (stop this service option on the left after clicking on the service name) or double clicked on it and clicked STOP (if this service status is Started).
3. Web deployment Service (not the exact name though it has Web deployment at the beginning). Stop this service too (the same way as above).

If you are running Skype, exit out of that too, run Apache, then launch Skype